# Android 12 won't lock to portrait mode properly

Tags: android, react-native

So I've added the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
```

and it is working on older versions of Android as expected, but once I get to Android 12 this happens (on tablets and on phones):
[image: picture of issue]

Is there a way to force it into portrait mode and stay that way regardless of which way is up for the phone? I thought that was `sensorPortrait` but I'm using `portrait`?

Comment: What do you expect it to do in this case? The device is in landscape mode. Do you want your app to be oriented at a 90 degree angle so that the user has to tilt his head to use it?

Comment: I want to disable landscape mode and just lock it to portrait only. So yes, the user will need to rotate the phone back upright to not tilt his/her head.

Comment: Try setting `android:resizeableActivity="false"`. Android 12 makes multi-window mode the default and this may be what you are seeing.

Comment: You might also try calling `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` in that `Activity`.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? If so would you mind sharing what you did?